# Can't boot windows 8.1

Tags: dual-boot

after install the Ubuntu, i can't boot the windows 8.1, blue screen appears on my monitor (said Your PC ran into problem and need to restart, we’re just collecting some error info … )

```
i’ve tried to use windows 8.1 iso image with live usb and not working at all
```

i need suggestion thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably removed Microsoft reserved partition and therefore it's not booting. You can open the Disks application on Ubuntu and check the disk partitioning, then look for Microsoft reserved partition. If it's not available it's uninstalled and you need to reinstall it again, but I suggest you run `sudo update-grub` after Windows installation, because Windows Boot Manager is not compatible with Linux.

[image]